# PHP styling while for

Tags: php

Glad you are here. I need solution and I am kinda newbie in these things.
Right now I have page looking like this

```
1.text    2.text    3.text    4.text
```

but I need it to be like this

```
1.text    2.text
3.text    4.text
```

Code I have

```
<table >
        <?php
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++): ?>
        <tr>
        <?php while($row = $choices->fetch_assoc()): ?>
          <td><button class="pogaAtbilzuVarianti" value="<?php  echo $row['id_var']; ?>" id="atbilde_a"><?php  echo $row['teksts']; ?></button></td>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tr>
      <?php endfor; ?>
      </table>
```

Comment: Check if `$i` divides evenly into two. If it does, end your row and start a new one.

Comment: You've got your loops inside out... So you want to loop through your database results in the outer loop (Your WHILE Loop) and then perform your count check internal to that to generate the new rows for every 2 entries.

Comment: Thank you for tips and hints :) @TimBrownlaw

Comment: And you too @miken32  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for()` loop is useless in this, because the `while()` loop inside it will process every row returned by the query.

You should just use the `while` loop, and then use a counter to tell whether to start a new `<tr>`.

```
<table>
<?php
$counter = 0;
while ($row = $choices->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($counter % 2 == 0) { // Start a new row before event elements
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    ?>
    <td><button class="pogaAtbilzuVarianti" value="<?php  echo $row['id_var']; ?>" id="atbilde_a"><?php  echo $row['teksts']; ?></button></td>
    <?php
    if ($counter % 2 == 1) { // End row after odd elements
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    $counter++;
}
if ($counter % 2 == 1) { // End last row if it only had 1 column
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table >   
    <?php while($row = $choices->fetch_assoc()): 
    if(($row['id_var'] % 2) == 1) echo '<tr>';
    ?>
      <td><button class="pogaAtbilzuVarianti" value="<?php  echo $row['id_var']; ?>" id="atbilde_a"><?php  echo $row['teksts']; ?></button></td>
    <?php 
    if(($row['id_var'] % 2) == 0)  echo '</tr>';
    endwhile; ?>  
</table>
```